# Frida python redirect outpout to file

Tags: python, frida

I'm using frida-python to hook android function and I'm trying to redirect the output to a file.

I've tried to redirect stdout to a file :

```
sys.stdout = open(os.path.join(self.dump_path,'apk_hook.txt'), 'w')
```

before calling

```
script = self.session.create_script(open("java_hook.js").read())
script.load()
```

But this redirect everything and not just the result of frida-python.

I've also tried to write the result in a file directly in the javascript file (java_hook.js)
but i don't know how to pass my variable self.dump_path from my python file to my javascript file.

```
Java.use('java.net.URL').$init.overload('java.lang.String').implementation = function(str1) {
     var file = new File(How_can_i_pass_this_dynamic_variable,"w");
     file.write("helloworld");
     return this.$init(str1);
};
```

Do you know how can i do it ??

Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware that the JavaScript part is execute on-device? Therefore any created file would be created on-device, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `send`

```js
Java.use('java.net.URL').$init.overload('java.lang.String').implementation = function(str1) {
     send(dynamic_variable);
     return this.$init(str1);
};
```

In the python side

```py
f = open('/tmp/log', 'w')    
# ...
def on_message(msg, _data):
    f.write(msg['payload'] + '\n')
# ...
script.on('message', on_message)
```

Unless you want to write to a file on the phone

```js
    var f = new File("/sdcard/log.txt", "w");
    f.write("line\n");
    f.flush();
    f.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that Javascript is executed on the phone, which means you can only write  a file on the phone as mentioned by whoopdedoo.
If that is what you need, you should edit accordingly the following snippet:

```
var f = new File("/sdcard/log.txt", "w");
f.write("line\n");
f.flush();
f.close();
```

To write a file directly on your system (tested on windows/macos), I always use  `> file.txt` at the end of my frida command line:

```
frida -U -l myscript.js -f com.target.app.org --no-pause > file.txt
```

You will find `file.txt` in the folder where you executed the frida cmd.